# Nonhomogeneous linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

How can I solve the following equation:

$$z^2y''(z)+\frac{1}{\gamma}zy'(z)(\gamma-a_1-a_2 z)+\frac{1}{\gamma^2}y(z)(b_1+b_2z+b_3 z^2)=0$$

Apparently I am supposed to get to a confluent hypergeometric equation but I don't know how.

Comment: have you missed a y out of the last term?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

HINT : Change of variable and function 
$$\begin{cases}
z=\alpha x \\
y(z)=x^\beta e^{\mu x}u(x)
\end{cases}$$
In the transformed ODE, determine the parameters $\alpha$ , $\beta$ , $\mu$ to simplify it to the confluent hypergeometric form:
$$xu''(x)+(C-x)u'(x)-Au(x)=0$$
This will lead to the expressions of $\alpha$ , $\beta$ , $\mu$ , $A$ and $C$ as functions of the parameters present in the original ODE. Boring calculus, perseverance and good luck !